# how to manage a series of API calls in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, httprequest, async.js

I have a series of API endpoints that I need to poll in series in order to build up a canonical list:

```
/cities
/homes
/parcelvalue
```

so that polling `/cities` gives me a list of cities, polling `/homes` gives me a list of all addresses in a given city, and polling `/parcelvalue` gives me the value of a given home.

Ultimately, I am going to build up a file tree that saves the incremental output of polling each endpoint into a directory for auditing purposes:

```
|
\-cities/cities.json
|
\-homes/homes.json
|
\-parcelvalue/parcelvalue.json
```

so that `cities.json` is the raw output of the `/cities` enpoint, `homes.json` contains the results of polling the `/homes` endpoint for each city in `cities.json`, and `parcelvalue.json` contains the output of polling the `/parcelvalue` endpoint for each home in `homes.json`. I want each step to rely on disk I/O, so that the function that builds `homes.json` starts with the `cities.json` file.

The easiest way that I can see to do this would be by having each step 1. synchronously load the file that might inform it, 2. synchronously poll the appropriate end point, and then 3. synchronously saving the file that each function might generate:

a `getCities()` function might check to see if `cities.json` existed, and produce that file from the endpoint if it did not, a `getHomes()` function might import `cities.json` and then poll the `/homes` endpoint for each city in its list and then generate `homes.json`, and a `getParcelValues()` function might import `homes.json` and then poll the `/parcelvalue` endpoint for each home in its list and then generate `parcelvalue.json`

(this is a simplification, I'd like to add by-function filtering and error-handling, etc., but I'm trying to keep this example focused.)

Unfortunately, a thorough examination of synchronous http request libraries this evening hasn't resulted in any that will work in my circumstance.

Is there a good way to use something like [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) or another similar async workflow library to make use of, i.e. the async [request](https://github.com/request/request) library? I would like each of these functions to be called in series, `getCities()` -> `getHomes()` -> `getParcelValues()`, and to be encapsulated as much as might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

var async = require('async');

```
    async.auto({
        cities : function(cb) {
    //do your stuff ...
            if (err)
                cb(null, false);
            else 
                cb(null, result);
        },
        homes : ['cities', function(cb, result) {
            if(!result.cities)
                cb(null, false)
            else {
                // do your stuff
                if (err)
                    cb(null, false);
                else 
                    cb(null, homeResult);
            }
        }], 
        parcels : ['homes', function(cb, result) {
            if(!result.homes)
                cb(null, false)
            else {
                // do your stuff
                if (err)
                    cb(null, false);
                else 
                    cb(null, parcelResult);
            }
        }]
    },function(err, allResults){
        //do final works
    });
```